# can't find symbol IonicErrorHandler exported from module

Tags: ionic2

I want to see how IonicErrorHandler could be useful to me. so I added this on top of my app.components.ts

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule ,IonicErrorHandler} from 'ionic-angular';
```

and this at bottom

```
  providers: [{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}]
```

But I got this error on building .

> ngc error: Error: can't find symbol IonicErrorHandler exported from
>   module
>   /node_modules/ionic-angular/index.d.ts,
>   resolving symbol AppModule in
>   /.tmp/app/app.module.ts,
>   resolving symbol AppModule in
>   /.tmp/app/app.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by uninstalling and re installing new ionic and cordova.

```
npm uninstall ionic cordova
npm install -g ionic cordova
```